# Function returning always false when using a Boolean on my statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$firstTime = 'SELECT first_time FROM tbl_user WHERE user_id = :id';

$FTQuery = $pdo->query($firstTime);
$bool = bool($FTQuery);
if($bool>0){
    redirect_to('./admin_edit.php');
} else {
    redirect_to('index.php');
}
```

I couldn't find an answer into how should i pull this from my database and use the boolean into the statement, I'm trying var_dump because i saw it in a similar post that it would solve the issue but it didn't.
Tried to use the $FTQuery variable as a statement, like

```
if($FTQuery>0)
```

but it wouldn't work.

Comment: Where are you setting `$bool`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Are you trying to check if any results were found in your select query? Is there more code in this script, because this doesn't seem complete.

Comment: Im checking whether it is the first time an user is logging in into my CMS, if it is i want to redirect him into the Change password page, if not, just the regular index.php page

Comment: Im sorry, i forgot to add where i set the bool variable, it is supposed to be $bool = bool($FTQuery);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PDO::query()` returns a `PDOStatement` object. If you want to get the value from the database, use [`fetchColumn()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) on that object. In addition, you have a placeholder that you aren't filling so you shouldn't even be using `query()` but `execute()` on a prepared statement. The cast to boolean is not necessary; PHP does this sort of thing automatically.

```php
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT first_time FROM tbl_user WHERE user_id = :id');
$stmt->execute(["id" => $id]);
$value = $stmt->fetchColumn();
redirect_to( $value ? './admin_edit.php' : 'index.php' );
```